# Windows Workflow Runtime (.NET 4.0) is randomly stuck (hanging) after scheduling a SequentialWorkflowActivity that is never run

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

This is my first post in the forum because a difficult issue that I have been trying to solve for 2 weeks has pushed me to do so.

Background: I am running WWF in .NET 4.0 within a .net WPF application that is running on windows XP. We start the workflow with the same activity many times a day, and 80% of the time the workflow completes successfully. 20% of the time the workflow is stuck, or hanging right after have we started.

We have reproduced the hanging issue in the debugger, with WF logging enabled. This is what the console output looks like:

```
System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : Creating instance 5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 0 : Queuing Service: Creating new Queue with ID -37063737 for *PendingNotifications

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : TimerEventSubscriptionQueue: 5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58 Created

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 0 : Adding context 1:New Recipe Workflow

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : WorkflowRuntime:: replacing unusable executor for key 5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58 with new one (hc: 21789324)

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : WorkflowRuntime dispensing resource instanceId: 5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58, hc: 21789324
System.Workflow.Runtime Transfer: 0 : , relatedActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

System.Workflow.Runtime Stop: 0 : Workflow Trace

System.Workflow.Runtime Transfer: 0 : , relatedActivityId=5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58

System.Workflow.Runtime Start: 0 : Workflow Trace

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 0 : Activity Status Change - Activity: New Recipe Workflow Old:Initialized; New:Executing

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58 : Scheduling entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)New Recipe Workflow, ActivityStatusChange('(1)New Recipe Workflow', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime.Tracking Information: 0 : TrackingListener::ActivityStatusChange - Received Activity Status Change Event for activity New Recipe Workflow
System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58 : Scheduling entry: ActivityOperation((1)New Recipe Workflow, Execute)

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : Scheduling work for instance 5d309d9c-1a35-46a1-b0df-e10c6ab04a58
System.Workflow.Runtime Transfer: 0 : , relatedActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

System.Workflow.Runtime Stop: 0 : Workflow Trace

The thread '<No Name>' (0x15d0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x23bc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b44) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2fa0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

(end of debug log)
```

Working Case:

```
System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : Creating instance 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 0 : Queuing Service: Creating new Queue with ID -37063737 for *PendingNotifications

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : TimerEventSubscriptionQueue: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 Created

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 0 : Adding context 1:New Recipe Workflow

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : WorkflowRuntime:: replacing unusable executor for key 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 with new one (hc: 7648267)

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : WorkflowRuntime dispensing resource instanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63, hc: 7648267

System.Workflow.Runtime Transfer: 0 : , relatedActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

System.Workflow.Runtime Stop: 0 : Workflow Trace

System.Workflow.Runtime Transfer: 0 : , relatedActivityId=744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63

System.Workflow.Runtime Start: 0 : Workflow Trace

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 0 : Activity Status Change - Activity: New Recipe Workflow Old:Initialized; New:Executing

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Scheduling entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)New Recipe Workflow, ActivityStatusChange('(1)New Recipe Workflow', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime.Tracking Information: 0 : TrackingListener::ActivityStatusChange - Received Activity Status Change Event for activity New Recipe Workflow

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Scheduling entry: ActivityOperation((1)New Recipe Workflow, Execute)

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : Scheduling work for instance 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63

System.Workflow.Runtime Transfer: 0 : , relatedActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting Information: 0 : Running workflow 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63

System.Workflow.Runtime Transfer: 0 : , relatedActivityId=744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63

System.Workflow.Runtime Start: 0 : Workflow Trace

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)New Recipe Workflow, ActivityStatusChange('(1)New Recipe Workflow', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Done with running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)New Recipe Workflow, ActivityStatusChange('(1)New Recipe Workflow', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Running scheduled entry: ActivityOperation((1)New Recipe Workflow, Execute)

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 0 : Activity Status Change - Activity: Delay Old:Initialized; New:Executing

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Scheduling entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Scheduling entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Scheduling entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime.Tracking Information: 0 : TrackingListener::ActivityStatusChange - Received Activity Status Change Event for activity Delay

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Scheduling entry: ActivityOperation((1)Delay, Execute)

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Done with running scheduled entry: ActivityOperation((1)New Recipe Workflow, Execute)

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Done with running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Done with running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Done with running scheduled entry: SubscriptionEvent((1)Delay, ActivityStatusChange('(1)Delay', Executing, None))

System.Workflow.Runtime Information: 1 : Workflow Runtime: Scheduler: InstanceId: 744f3ca1-5ea1-49bb-aa2b-72b1233fcc63 : Running scheduled entry: ActivityOperation((1)Delay, Execute)


(app continues running workflow...)
```

From what I see in the logs, both broken and working states schedule the activity. The broken (stuck) state does not actually run the activity after scheduling.

This truly happens at random and with no exception, and when I examine the threads, there is nothing to point me towards the activity/workflow waiting on any event.

Any advice in debugging this issue is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bumping for more views.

Comment: Do you have any activity level tracking, which shows the execution of the contained activities.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the working case. The execution activities are showing in my logs. Unfortunately, it never executes an activity in the broken state, since WF's queue is not running them.